Monolayer graphene band structure with SOC
Anyone guide me how can we find spin orbital coupling band structure in monolayer graphene using Quantum ESPRESSO.
What should we do?

In Quantum Espresso, to calculate band structure, you need to use from this procedure:

Create input file for scf calculation.
If you want to include spin orbit coupling (SOC), you have to use from fully relativistic pseudopotentials instead of scalar one. Besides, you have to add noncolin = .t., lspinorb = .t. and starting_magnetization(i) to CONTROL card of scf input file.
After finishing scf calculation, perform bands calculation. In this case you have to change only calculation='bands' and K_POINTS card. I suppose that you use from automatic kpoints grid in scf. Choose your band structure path. Then change KPOINTS card from scf with it. You will have input file for bands calculation.
Bands calculation generates wfc files, they can be converted to plottable format using bands.x. It is included in Quantum Espresso.

To better understand, you can use from this tutorial. Calculation of band structure and using from SOC are explained in detail with examples.

SIR i m done all of these steps but graphene mono-layer didn't show spin orbital coupling in their band structure, because they have no magnetic property.. but i literature i was see graphene band structure With SOC. that way I'm so confused.. plz guide me
